# ADVANCED EXCEL HELP: Divide when multiple conditions are satisfied.

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

Hi I am currently working on a large data spreadsheet and want to divide only when all conditions are satisfied. Below is the sample data

Article UOM Quantity

1002121 CAS 500

1002121 EA  1

1002121 INN 10

1002121 LAY 2,000

1002121 PAL 10,000

1002127 CAS 500

1002127 CS1 250

1002127 CS2 10

1002127 EA  1

1002127 INN 10

1002127 LAY 3,000

1002127 PAL 12,000

1002129 CAS 500

1002129 CS1 250

1002129 EA  1

1002129 INN 10

1002129 LAY 1,750

1002129 PAL 7,000

Column 1 is SKU nos, Column 2 is unit of measure and column 3 is quantity

What I want to know is how many cases(CAS) = one layer(LAY) when SKU is same.

E.g.: for SKU 1002121, one layer will be equal to 4 cases (2000/4)(LAY/CAS).

Hence I need a formula which satisfies three conditions 
1. SKU must be the same
2. when column b=LAY and Column B=CAS then divide column C and show result in column D in layer's Row

Thanks for your help. Any suggestion is welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This expression is rather a complicated one:

```
=IF(B2="CAS",SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,"LAY")/SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,"CAS"),"")
```

(or

```
=IF(B2="CAS";SUMIFS($C:$C;$A:$A;$A2;$B:$B;"LAY")/SUMIFS($C:$C;$A:$A;$A2;$B:$B;"CAS");"")
```

if your locale uses as delimiters `;` instead of `,`)

Put in in the cell `D2` and copy it to cells in the column D just bellow it.

**Explanation**:

- `IF` decides if it is a cell where you want put the result.
- The result is a *quotient*. Both the *dividend* and *divisor* use almost the same formula.
- `SUMIFS($C:$C,$A:$A,$A2,$B:$B,"LAY")` details:

  1. `$C:$C` is the range of numbers for creating the sum (in your case from only `1` number)
  2. `$A:$A` is the range for making comparisons with:
  3. `$A2` a value to be compared with
  4. Next 2 parameters have the same meaning as 2nd and 3rd, they make an another condition.
  5. So there are 2 conditions. They are evaluated *again and again for each pair of corresponding cells* in the columns A and B (so A2 and B2, A3 and B3, etc.) and if *both* of them are satisfied, the corresponding cell from the 1st argument (i. e. C2, C3, etc.) are included to the sum (in your case *at most* `1` cell).

Comment: Thanks Marian, This worked like a miracle. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make a pivot table with your table as source. You would then put SKU in the filter and UOM in column fields. In the UOM you just filter the CAS and LAY. Then you get your numbers for CAS and LAY, which you just need to divide. You can also do the division in a pivot table calculated field.